# anonymous setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

i have a situation where i am waiting for a couple of events to happen.  i see many good examples of how to use the setTimeout using a named function, but is there a way to use some sort of anonymous method for a timeout?

the code currently looks something like this:

```
testForObject();

function testForObject() {
    if  ( typeof marksObjectName === 'object' )  {
           // blah blah
    } else {
       console.log('marksObjectName does not exist quite yet');
       setTimeout(function() { testForObject() }, 500 );
    }
}
```

so i was wondering if there is some way naming the function during setTimeout and use an anonymous method instead, perhaps something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if  ( typeof marksObjectName === 'object' )  {
           // blah blah
    } else {
       console.log('marksObjectName does not exist quite yet');
    }
}, 500);
```

obviously this does not work, but it was my first (and only) guess.

thank you all very much.

Comment: have you considered using promises instead of timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the function as follows.  Note that you will need to put it within another timeout within the `else` clause:

```js
setTimeout(function timer() {
  if (typeof marksObjectName === 'object') {
    // blah blah
  } else {
    console.log('marksObjectName does not exist quite yet');
    setTimeout(timer, 500);
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: this might be the best answer - i was hoping to avoid using any function names at all but that might not be possible.  however, your suggestion is certainly very readable and intuitive.  a function name can be chosen that is pretty obvious the name not referenced outside this block of code.   thank you.

Comment: i have selected this answer.    i was able to use your solution and embed another setTimeout using your model.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can name the passed function, like

```
setTimeout(function myFunction() {
    // ...
}, 500);
```

Comment: i had hoped to avoid using any function names at all to keep things anonymous.

Comment: There is the deprecated arguments.callee which will point to the anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

I believe hat `setInterval` is what you are looking for.

`setInterval(function() {
    if  ( typeof marksObjectName === 'object' )  {
           // blah blah
    } else {
       console.log('marksObjectName does not exist quite yet');
    }
}, 500);`

Comment: You'll want to keep a reference to the interval so you can use clearInterval(interval) when the code is ready to stop looking.